# change more characters in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

my problem is the follow:

I ask a string from somebody (for example: This is the text):

```
a = input("Enter a text: "))
```

I would like the change every vowel like this: e->eve, a->ava, i->ivi, u->uvu, o->ovo with for cycle
Finally I would print the new text

My solution is:

```
b = a.replace('o', 'ovo').replace('u', 'uvu')
print(b)
```

But this does not use the for cycle

could you help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by for-cycle you mean for loop?

For this transformation you can use a lookup-dictionary in combination with a for-loop. Two toy examples:

```
transforms = {'a':'ava',
              'e':'eve',
              'i':'ivi',
              'u':'uvu',
              'o':'ovo'}

test_string = 'This is some text'
```

First you can create a new string with the replaced words:

```
new_string = ''

for char in test_string:
    if char in transforms:
        new_string += transforms[char]
    else:
        new_string += char
```

Which yields 'Thivis ivis sovomeve tevext'.

Or you may convert the original to a list and replace elements using the dictionary (and finally join your list):

```
test_string = list(test_string)

for i, ch in enumerate(test_string):
    if ch in transforms:
        test_string[i] = transforms[ch]

test_string = ''.join(test_string)
```

Which also yields 'Thivis ivis sovomeve tevext'

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through a string in Python with `for c in "string":`

Using this, you could solve your problem by

```
newString=""
for c in a:
    if c in ["a", "e", "i", "o" "u", "y"]:
        newString+=c+"v"+c
    else:
        newString+=c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
     a = a.replace(c, c+'v'+c)
print(a)
```

You can create a previous copy of a if you need the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! The whole solution is:

```
transforms = {'a':'ava',
              'e':'eve',
              'i':'ivi',
              'u':'uvu',
              'o':'ovo',
              'ö':'övö',
              'ü':'üvü',
              'ó':'óvó',
              'ő':'ővő',
              'ú':'úvú',
              'é':'évé',
              'á':'ává',
              'ű':'űvű',
              'í':'ívi'}

test_string = input('Írj be egy tetszőleges szöveget, amit ivigyelek: ')

new_string = ''

for char in test_string:
    if char in transforms:
        new_string += transforms[char]
    else:
        new_string += char

print(new_string)
```